# Embedding an existing UINavigationController to new view controllers

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

Suppose I have a storyboard with a navigation controller and several view controllers.

All is well until I try to add a new view controller and would like to associate it with the existing `UINavigationController`. When I go to Editor>Embed>Navigation Controller, Xcode helpfully creates a new controller, which is precisely what I don't want. When I attempt to drag to create a wireframe, I create a segue relationship, which again is what I don't want.

Is there a way to make new view controllers play nice with an existing nav controller?

Comment: How will your new view controller be associated to your nav controller, if not through a push segue?

Comment: Shouldn't there be another association? When I embed a new nav controller Xcode does not create push segues, but a different kind of wire connection

Comment: Also when I create just a push segue, the view controller's height is not adjusted at runtime and the nav controller's nav bar will obscure the very top part of the view. I noticed the views that were in the project originally dont suffer this, only views added later on and connected to a nav controller via push segue.

Comment: You are correct, the connection between a Nav Controller and the first viewcontroller is not a push segue, it's a special relationship that exists between the nav controller and it's root ViewController.  When using a push segue to push another controller on the nav stack you can have your controller's view and subviews adjust to the shorter height by setting the autoresizingMask propery appropriately.  However, it sounds like maybe what you are looking for is a modal segue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are thinking of the UINavigationController incorrectly. UINavigationController is just a container view controller that manages a hierarchy of view controllers. You start with one UINavigationController, which has exactly one root view controller (it sounds like you want more than one, which isn't going to happen). When you push a new view controller, it is pushed onto the same UINavigationController. So if you want multiple view controllers associated with a single UINavigationController, they have to hierarchically stack onto the root view controller.